# What are REST standards for PUT and POST methods?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, post, put

I am implementing API in Laravel and get comment that my POST and PUT methods are not accurate according to the REST standards.

I am using POST for create new resource and PUT for updating existing one. Can not see problem.

endpoints:

```php
Route::post('/cities', [
    'uses' => 'CityController@store'
]);

Route::put('/cities/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'CityController@update'
]);
```

**`PUT`** and **`POST`** method :

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'      => 'required|min:3',
        'latitude'  => 'required|numeric',
        'longitude' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);

    // update model and only pass in the fillable fields
    $this->cityRepository->update(
        $request->only($this->cityRepository->getModel()->fillable), $id
    );

    return $this->cityRepository->show($id);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'      => 'required|min:3',
        'latitude'  => 'required|numeric',
        'longitude' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);

    $data = $this->cityRepository->create(
        $request->only($this->cityRepository->getModel()->fillable));

    if ($data) {
        $message = self::SUCCESSFULLY_CREATED;
        $code = self::HTTP_CODE_CREATED;
    } else {
        $message = self::UNSUCCESSFULLY_CREATED;
        $code = 409;
    }

    return $this->sendResponse($message, $data, $code);
}
```

Send response:

```
public function sendResponse($message, $result = [], $code = 200)
    {
        $response = [
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        if (!empty($result)) {
            $response['data'] = $result;
        }

        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }
```

Show method:

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    }
```

Comment: Who says that POST to create and PUT to update are not accurate according to the REST standards?

Comment: Not that POST to create and PUT to update are not accurate according to the REST standards but that my methods are not implemented accurate according to the REST standards. And I don't understand why.

Comment: Well the one thing I can see which is a bit off is sending the 409 response code. 409 means "conflict" but here you don't really know if the reason is "conflict" it could be that the database is down in which case there's no conflict. Other than that it probably also depends on how `sendResponse` and `show` are implemented.

Comment: I add code from `sendResponse` and `show` methods. Yes probably 409 is not good for returning in this case.

Comment: When you create a resource your response should be 201 and the result should be the newly created resource and not a message if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the created object from your `store` method instead of `SUCCESSFULLY_CREATED`. Aside from that the code looks good.

Take a look at the table on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers, which has a fairly useful REST definition of various CRUD routes:

```
GET         /photos                 index       photos.index
GET         /photos/create          create      photos.create
POST        /photos                 store       photos.store
GET         /photos/{photo}         show        photos.show
GET         /photos/{photo}/edit    edit        photos.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}         update      photos.update
DELETE      /photos/{photo}         destroy     photos.destroy
```

Here's a good resource for which HTTP methods you should return:

https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html